# Entity Framework returns null on calling stored procedure with temp table even after setting datacontract

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure as follows. Please see the line 1=2 is for setting the datacontext. I read this from one of the posts here. In my C# code I am calling this stored procedure as follows. I can see the result for the stored procedure just fine in the database. I can see 2 result records in the database.

But calling from C# code below returns count 2 but with null and 0 for both the records. Please help.

```
public class UnreadAlerts
{
        public string alertName { get; set; }
        public int alertValue { get; set; }
}

public List<UnreadAlerts> AllUnreadAlertsCount(int userId)
{
    List<UnreadAlerts> Sdetails = new List<UnreadAlerts>();

    using (var context1 = new AltusEntities())
    {
        Sdetails = context1.Database.SqlQuery<UnreadAlerts>("[dbo].[sp_UnreadAlertsCount] @userid",
                new SqlParameter("@userid", userId)
                ).ToList();
    }

    return Sdetails;
}
```

Stored procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_UnreadAlertsCount]  
    @userId int  
AS
BEGIN
    IF 1 = 2 
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            cast(null as nvarchar(50))  as Aname
            ,cast(null as int)    as Avalue
        WHERE
            1 = 2  
    END

    CREATE TABLE #Results  
    (  
        Aname nvarchar(50),  
        Avalue int  
    )  

    INSERT INTO #Results (Aname, Avalue)  
        SELECT
            'ProximityAlerts',
            COUNT(DISTINCT ProximityMeetingAlertID) 
        FROM
            AltusRt.dbo.ProximityMeetingAlerts pma  
        JOIN
            AltusRt.dbo.ProximityMeetings pm ON pma.ProximityMeetingID = pm.ProximityMeetingID  
        WHERE
            pm.RequestID IN (SELECT r.RequestId 
                             FROM Users u 
                             JOIN Requests r ON u.UserId = r.CreatedByUserId
                             WHERE u.UserId = @userId 
                               AND r.CreatedByUserId = @userId)  

        INSERT INTO #Results (Aname,Avalue)  
            SELECT
                'MonitorAlerts',
                COUNT(*) 
            FROM 
                dbo.TargetGeoFenceResult 
            WHERE
                ActiveStatus = 1  

        SELECT Aname, Avalue 
        FROM #Results
    END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names and the property names didn't match. As a result, the values weren't never copied to the `UnreadAlerts` instance and you are presented with the default value of `int` and `string`.

Now you can fix it by changing the property names :

```
public class UnreadAlerts
{
    public string Aname{ get; set; }
    public int Avalue { get; set; }
}
```

Or, by aliasing with [`[ColumnAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
public class UnreadAlerts
{
    [Column(Name = "Aname")]
    public string alertName { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "Avalue")]
    public int alertValue { get; set; }
}
```